# Search bar searching combined API React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest, search

Im making a small school project with a react frontend showing different characters from tv shows/movies.

I printed these chars out into some tabels, fetched from 3 different APIs  (Harry Potter, Star Wars and GoT)

On the frontpage of the site i want to have a search bar function where you can search for characters in all 3 apis and show them in a table/modal (doesnt matter for now) Therefor i combined the 3 APIs into one endpoint containing them all in an array [image]

Im having some troubles making this search bar function. I want to have a search bar where can write part of the name of a character and it will suggest or show a character based on that (ex. Harr should show/suggest Harry Potter)

So far my code looks like this:

```
export default function Search({ searchingForChar }) {
  const init = [{ name: "", fullName: "" }];
  const [allCharacters, setAllCharacters] = useState(init);

  const fetchData = () => {
    console.log("test");
    if (searchingForChar !== "" || searchingForChar !== undefined) {
      searchFacade
        .searchForAllChars()
        .then((data) =>
          setAllCharacters([
            ...data.swList.results,
            ...data.hpList.hpDTOList,
            ...data.gotList.results,
          ])
        );
    }
  };

  useEffect(fetchData, [searchingForChar]);

  return (
    <>
      {allCharacters
        .filter((char) => char.name.includes(searchingForChar))
        .map((filteredPerson) => (
          <>
            <h1>Her burde stå et navn: {filteredPerson.name}</h1>
          </>
        ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

And is used in the Form here:

```
export default function Home() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(),
    onInput = ({ target: { value } }) => setValue(value),
    onFormSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(value);
      setValue();
    };

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid padding">
      <img className="logo" src={Dachma} alt=""></img>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-3"></div>
        <div className="col-6 text-center">
          <h4 className="mt-5">Search for your favorite character</h4>
          <Form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
            <Form.Control onChange={onInput} placeholder="Search here.." />
            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
              Type character name, movie, tv show etc.
            </Form.Text>
            <MDBBtn
              outline
              color="primary"
              rounded
              size="m"
              type="submit"
              className="mr-auto"
            >
              Search
            </MDBBtn>
          </Form>
          <Search searchingFor={value} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-3"></div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-2"></div>
        <div className="col-8">
          <h4 className="mt-5 text-center">Current shows in the site:</h4>
          <p className="mt-2 text-muted text-center">
            Click to get info about a movie/tv show.
          </p>
          <div className="flexDirection: row justifyContent: space-between">
            <Card imgToDisplay={gotImg} />
            <Card imgToDisplay={hpImg} />
            <Card imgToDisplay={swImg} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tried many different ways found here on stack and other places, i just cant seem to getting it to work as intended

Ive had many different errors but for now im stuck on "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined.

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Please know that im a beginner to react/JS, so please explain if you can help.

Comment: you are filtering like `.filter((char) => char.name.includes(searchingForChar)` but in the data i see `fullName` like  `"fullName":"John Snow"`  is it correct?

Comment: Correct, but the HP / Star Wars APIs names is "name": "Harry Potter"